# Make rsync working with compressed target or tar creating no increment files

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, tar

I need to make a backup on my external hard drive. I looked both at rsync and incremental tar. The problem is that I want my backup to be compressed. With rsync I can only compress the data transfer, but not the result. With tar the result is indeed compressed, but I will have a lot of incremental archives, when I want to have just one compressed file.
So, I see 2 options: either I need rsync, that works with compressed target or tar, that creates just one file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

rsync doesn't have the capability to compress it's target.  One possibility is to store your backup copy on a filesystem that supports native transparent compression (for example btrfs) which will provide you with the space saving you are looking for.